# Custom post type permalink tag 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

I'm using [wp-types](http://www.wp-types.com) to build a wordpress site. I'm happy with the types and their fields, I just wanted to created a function that shows parents in the url - see blow function that achieves this - also using the Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin to add my custom tag %parents% to the url.

The rewrite seems to work fine, displays in the back end etc. But when you click view document - 404.php.

I've tried rewrite flushing - mod rewrite definitely works, as friendly permalinks work for pages and don't 404, it's only on the custom post types.

My ideal url structure is: %sector%/%parents%/%postname% - Sector being a custom taxonomy. The custom taxonomy also displays fine because of the CPTP plugin but 404s as well.

wp-types does have rewrite functions but they are all turned off. it's really got me stumped, the code below is included in my functions.php - I am using bones starter theme.

Should I include this code as a plugin instead? Or is there something i've missed? The only way I can get access the items is by setting permalinks to default.

```
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'parents_post_rewrite_function', 10, 3); 

  function parents_post_rewrite_function( $post_link, $id = 0, $leavename = FALSE ) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    $postID = $post->ID;

    // Always globalize $wpdb
    global $wpdb;

    // Get current posts parent type
    $parentType = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT  `meta_key` FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `post_id` ={$postID} AND `meta_key` LIKE '%belongs%'");

    // Get current posts parentID if project
    $parentID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT  `meta_value` FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `post_id` ={$postID} AND  `meta_key` =  '{$parentType}'" );

    if(!empty($parentID)){

    // Get parent parent posts type
    $parentParentType = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT  `meta_key` FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `post_id` ={$parentID} AND `meta_key` LIKE '%belongs%'");

    // Try and get same value from parent ID, if fails then no parent of parent 
    $parentParentID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT  `meta_value` FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `post_id` ={$parentID} AND  `meta_key` =  '{$parentParentType}'" );

    }

    if(!empty($parentParentID)){
            $parentslug = get_post($parentID)->post_name;
            $parentparentslug = get_post($parentParentID)->post_name;
            $parents = $parentparentslug.'/'.$parentslug;
    } else {
        $parents = get_post($parentID)->post_name;
    }

    // Get parents parent post ID & continue until none found
    // Convert IDs to names and render slug

    return str_replace('%parents%', $parents, $post_link);
  }
```

Comment: the `post_type_link` filter is just for functions that output permalinks, it has nothing to do with generating rewrite rules for incoming requests for those permalinks.

Comment: I see. I'm new to wordpress, what should I be using to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I cloned my site to set up a development server - for me, it working by setting permalinks to ugly, saving, then setting them to pretty again, which rebuilt whatever had gone wrong in htaccess.